# Xcode clear build errors after a few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have Xcode 14.3.

When building my project Xcode shows few errors.  Without doing anything, the errors are cleared a few seconds later from the Issue Navigator and the red indicator right from "Build Failed | Today 11:30" disappears at the same time.

(Errors still show up in Report Navigator.)

Restarting Xcode and cleaning build folder didn't help.

I don't remember changing any Xcode settings recently.

What could this be?

EDIT: I upgraded to Xcode 14.3.1 and the issue disappeared.

Comment: I’m noticing this too but I’m using C++. Seems like it only started with a recent update. It’s certainly frustrating. Of course that’s not the solution; just a reflection on the experience. Hope someone has already figured this out.

Comment: Hmmm, after making minor code changes things are working again (i.e., any errors remain visible now).  EDIT: And it's back again with a bit more minor code changes a few minutes later.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [Xcode 14.3.1 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14_3_1-release-notes) about this undesired behavior having been fixed. I may not be seeing it occur anymore either however since upgrading to 14.3.1. I didn't experience it all the time with 14.3 though. I'm gonna definitely be paying more attention now though LOLs!

Comment: I'm still noticing build errors disappearing a few seconds after appearing in Xcode 14.3.1.

Comment: Looks like this question is same/similar to older question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73808435/xcode-errors-disappear. There are answers for that question which sounds like possible solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode errors disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73808435/xcode-errors-disappear). The answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76045861/7410358), fixes this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode currently has a feature (?) where it hides some "known" errors automatically. In my experience they are most often related to Swift 6 concurrency.

Comment: My errors were 'regular' ones, and Xcode 14.3 does not support Swift 6.